# How to add the Schema.org markup (generated by the Structured Data Markup Helper) to specific WordPress pages?

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, google-search-console

I have used the Structured Data Markup Helper and now need to add my mark-up code. Do I add this to the main head section of the website or just the individual page head.

I assume this needs to be added to the specific page head but I'm not sure where to access this. I am using Wordpress and normally add mark-up to the child theme header.php file in my cPanel but this is for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(is_page('home')){  ?><!-- home page with slug home
      enter your schema code for homepage -->
   <?php }
   else if(is_page('career')){ ?><!-- career page with slug career
      enter your schema code for career-->
   <?php }
```